# Do you have to strongly name assemblies to run multiple versions of the same assembly in WF?

Tags: c#, assemblies, workflow-foundation

I'm having to maintain a system running windows workflow foundation, changes need to be made to the Workflows so I'm developing them in a new version of the workflow project, say Version  2.0.0.0

I need to run Version 1.0.0.0 workflows, at the same time as Version 2.0.0.0 workflows, with new workflows being created using the latest assembly.

I've read [this great explanation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/10/versioning-long-running-workfows.aspx) on running multiple versions of workflows, and within my app.config I have the following:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="some.namespace.workflow" publicKeyToken="null" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="legacy/version_1_0_0_0/some.namespace.workflow.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

However, the new workflows always get created with version 1.0.0.0 - even though I've changed the version of the related Workflow project to 2.0.0.0

The only difference I can see is that my assemblies aren't strongly named, could this be what's causing it?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I think this problem might be related to the way I'm loading the assembly by using:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("some.namespace.workflow");
```

[This chap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/01/12/assembly-load-version-numbers-and-unsigned-assemblies.aspx) is suggesting that you need to strong name your assemblies to use the `Assembly.Load` method - is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the assembly containing your workflow should be strongly named. For me it was like, learn things the hard way. I created hundreds of WF instances and then I changed the WF structure. Once this was done, all the older instances failed because WF was unable to de-serialize them into proper objects. Ensure that before you push your WF codebase into production, you have strongly named all the relevant assemblies.

Comment: I have a serious case of Bull and Gate here, the system went live without strong naming, and it turns out that retrofitting strong names with WF is a total pain because of the all the serialisation it does :(

Comment: I programmed in WF 3.0 and followed that same blog that you have mentioned in your post. If you are referring the same blog, then I will assume, that you are also working with WF 3.0. "Strong Naming Of Assemblies", is the single most important piece of information, that every WF programmer should know. But unfortunately, no where its clearly documented or emphasized. In your case, what you can do is process all the existing instances using the old WF structure. And then ship new strongly named code-base and use that WF instance to further creation of new instances.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Won't I have a problem with loading in the old non-strongly named assembly (version 1.0.0.0) from the new strongly named assembly? I have tried signing all the assemblies before, and then tried to translate the old non-signed sigs to the newly signed ones - but I couldn't get the LocalService information corrected - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767067/how-to-version-the-local-service-layer-used-by-externaldataexchangeservice-in-wi)

Comment: I think yes you will have issues, while you try to process a WF instance which was created with a non-strongly named assembly by using a strongly named assembly. In the link that you gave, its the same, versioning of assemblies that is causing the problem. I tried my best to get this incompatibility issue resolved but I soon realized that I am out of luck. In short the the serialized & the de-serialized WF instance should be exactly same. Any kind of structural differences, should be taken care with the help of versioning.